# Laravel File Manager 404 error on Laravel 6

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

I've installed the [Uni Sharp File Manager](https://unisharp.github.io/laravel-filemanager/integration) for my laravel app with tinymce text editor.

I've followed each and every step of the installation guide and have copied the code snippet from the instructions of the package.

The text editor loads successfully.[image]

But when I click the file manager button (circled in red) a pop up window opens and loads my 404 error page.

My resource routes are only available to `auth` middleware:

```
Route::prefix('manage')->group(function () {
   Auth::routes(['register' => false]);

    Route::middleware('auth')->group(function () {
            Route::resource('post', 'PostController');
    });
});
```

Also checked route list it gives laravel file manager has the following middleware:

```
 | web,auth,UniSharp\LaravelFilemanager\Middlewares\CreateDefaultFolder,UniSharp\LaravelFilemanager\Middlewares\MultiUser |
```

Just checked in console I'm getting this error:

`tinymce.min.js:2 
GET https://upscaleadventures.com/laravel-filemanager?field_name=mceu_49-inp&type=Images 404`

Though I've published the vendor files and config files.

lfm.php file contents:

```js
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Documentation for this config :
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| online  => http://unisharp.github.io/laravel-filemanager/config
| offline => vendor/unisharp/laravel-filemanager/docs/config.md
 */

return [
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Routing
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
     */

    'use_package_routes'       => true,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Shared folder / Private folder
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | If both options are set to false, then shared folder will be activated.
    |
     */

    'allow_private_folder'     => true,

    // Flexible way to customize client folders accessibility
    // If you want to customize client folders, publish tag="lfm_handler"
    // Then you can rewrite userField function in App\Handler\ConfigHandler class
    // And set 'user_field' to App\Handler\ConfigHandler::class
    // Ex: The private folder of user will be named as the user id.
    'private_folder_name'      => UniSharp\LaravelFilemanager\Handlers\ConfigHandler::class,

    'allow_shared_folder'      => true,

    'shared_folder_name'       => 'shares',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Folder Names
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
     */

    'folder_categories'        => [
        'file'  => [
            'folder_name'  => 'files',
            'startup_view' => 'grid',
            'max_size'     => 50000, // size in KB
            'valid_mime'   => [
                'image/jpeg',
                'image/pjpeg',
                'image/png',
                'image/gif',
                'image/svg+xml',
            ],
        ],
        'image' => [
            'folder_name'  => 'photos',
            'startup_view' => 'list',
            'max_size'     => 50000, // size in KB
            'valid_mime'   => [
                'image/jpeg',
                'image/pjpeg',
                'image/png',
                'image/gif',
                'image/svg+xml',
                'application/pdf',
                'text/plain',
            ],
        ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Upload / Validation
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
     */

    'disk'                     => 'public',

    'rename_file'              => false,

    'alphanumeric_filename'    => false,

    'alphanumeric_directory'   => false,

    'should_validate_size'     => false,

    'should_validate_mime'     => false,

    // behavior on files with identical name
    // setting it to true cause old file replace with new one
    // setting it to false show `error-file-exist` error and stop upload
    'over_write_on_duplicate'  => false,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Thumbnail
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
     */

    // If true, image thumbnails would be created during upload
    'should_create_thumbnails' => true,

    'thumb_folder_name'        => 'thumbs',

    // Create thumbnails automatically only for listed types.
    'raster_mimetypes'         => [
        'image/jpeg',
        'image/pjpeg',
        'image/png',
    ],

    'thumb_img_width'          => 200, // px

    'thumb_img_height'         => 200, // px

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | File Extension Information
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
     */

    'file_type_array'          => [
        'pdf'  => 'Adobe Acrobat',
        'doc'  => 'Microsoft Word',
        'docx' => 'Microsoft Word',
        'xls'  => 'Microsoft Excel',
        'xlsx' => 'Microsoft Excel',
        'zip'  => 'Archive',
        'gif'  => 'GIF Image',
        'jpg'  => 'JPEG Image',
        'jpeg' => 'JPEG Image',
        'png'  => 'PNG Image',
        'ppt'  => 'Microsoft PowerPoint',
        'pptx' => 'Microsoft PowerPoint',
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | php.ini override
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | These values override your php.ini settings before uploading files
    | Set these to false to ingnore and apply your php.ini settings
    |
    | Please note that the 'upload_max_filesize' & 'post_max_size'
    | directives are not supported.
     */
    'php_ini_overrides'        => [
        'memory_limit' => '256M',
    ],
];
```

Comment: did you try to access the path to file manager directly?

Comment: Could you add your config/lfm.php config file ?

Comment: @niklaz I tried to access file manager

Comment: did you try to add LFM service providers manually in the config/app.php?

Comment: @niklaz No I didn't. I'm on laravel 6. There's no need to add service provider manually.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Added the following code in the `web.php` file:

```
 Route::group(['prefix' => 'laravel-filemanager', 'middleware' => ['web', 'auth']], function () {
 \UniSharp\LaravelFilemanager\Lfm::routes();
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my lfm config i used with Laravel Nova and it works fine

```
<?php

return [
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Routing
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */

    // Include to pre-defined routes from package or not. Middlewares
    'use_package_routes' => true,

    // Middlewares which should be applied to all package routes.
    // For laravel 5.1 and before, remove 'web' from the array.
    'middlewares' => ['web', 'auth'],

    // The url to this package. Change it if necessary.
    'url_prefix' => 'laravel-filemanager',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Multi-User Mode
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */

    // If true, private folders will be created for each signed-in user.
    'allow_multi_user' => true,
    // If true, share folder will be created when allow_multi_user is true.
    'allow_share_folder' => true,

    // Flexible way to customize client folders accessibility
    // If you want to customize client folders, publish tag="lfm_handler"
    // Then you can rewrite userField function in App\Handler\ConfigHander class
    // And set 'user_field' to App\Handler\ConfigHander::class
    // Ex: The private folder of user will be named as the user id.
    'user_field' => UniSharp\LaravelFilemanager\Handlers\ConfigHandler::class,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Working Directory
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */

    // Which folder to store files in project, fill in 'public', 'resources', 'storage' and so on.
    // You should create routes to serve images if it is not set to public.
    'base_directory' => 'public',

    'images_folder_name' => 'photos',
    'files_folder_name'  => 'files',

    'shared_folder_name' => 'shares',
    'thumb_folder_name'  => 'thumbs',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Startup Views
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */

    // The default display type for items.
    // Supported: "grid", "list"
    'images_startup_view' => 'grid',
    'files_startup_view' => 'list',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Upload / Validation
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */

    // If true, the uploaded file will be renamed to uniqid() + file extension.
    'rename_file' => false,

    // If rename_file set to false and this set to true, then non-alphanumeric characters in filename will be replaced.
    'alphanumeric_filename' => false,

    // If true, non-alphanumeric folder name will be rejected.
    'alphanumeric_directory' => false,

    // If true, the uploading file's size will be verified for over than max_image_size/max_file_size.
    'should_validate_size' => false,

    'max_image_size' => 50000,
    'max_file_size' => 50000,

    // If true, the uploading file's mime type will be valid in valid_image_mimetypes/valid_file_mimetypes.
    'should_validate_mime' => false,

    // available since v1.3.0
    'valid_image_mimetypes' => [
        'image/jpeg',
        'image/pjpeg',
        'image/png',
        'image/gif',
        'image/svg+xml',
    ],

    // If true, image thumbnails would be created during upload
    'should_create_thumbnails' => true,

    // Create thumbnails automatically only for listed types.
    'raster_mimetypes' => [
        'image/jpeg',
        'image/pjpeg',
        'image/png',
    ],

    // permissions to be set when create a new folder or when it creates automatically with thumbnails
    'create_folder_mode' => 0755,

    // permissions to be set on file upload.
    'create_file_mode' => 0644,

    // If true, it will attempt to chmod the file after upload
    'should_change_file_mode' => true,

    // available since v1.3.0
    // only when '/laravel-filemanager?type=Files'
    'valid_file_mimetypes' => [
        'image/jpeg',
        'image/pjpeg',
        'image/png',
        'image/gif',
        'image/svg+xml',
        'application/pdf',
        'text/plain',
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Image / Folder Setting
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */

    'thumb_img_width' => 200,
    'thumb_img_height' => 200,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | File Extension Information
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */

    'file_type_array' => [
        'pdf'  => 'Adobe Acrobat',
        'doc'  => 'Microsoft Word',
        'docx' => 'Microsoft Word',
        'xls'  => 'Microsoft Excel',
        'xlsx' => 'Microsoft Excel',
        'zip'  => 'Archive',
        'gif'  => 'GIF Image',
        'jpg'  => 'JPEG Image',
        'jpeg' => 'JPEG Image',
        'png'  => 'PNG Image',
        'ppt'  => 'Microsoft PowerPoint',
        'pptx' => 'Microsoft PowerPoint',
    ],

    'file_icon_array' => [
        'pdf'  => 'fa-file-pdf-o',
        'doc'  => 'fa-file-word-o',
        'docx' => 'fa-file-word-o',
        'xls'  => 'fa-file-excel-o',
        'xlsx' => 'fa-file-excel-o',
        'zip'  => 'fa-file-archive-o',
        'gif'  => 'fa-file-image-o',
        'jpg'  => 'fa-file-image-o',
        'jpeg' => 'fa-file-image-o',
        'png'  => 'fa-file-image-o',
        'ppt'  => 'fa-file-powerpoint-o',
        'pptx' => 'fa-file-powerpoint-o',
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | php.ini override
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | These values override your php.ini settings before uploading files
    | Set these to false to ingnore and apply your php.ini settings
    |
    | Please note that the 'upload_max_filesize' & 'post_max_size'
    | directives are not supported.
    */
    'php_ini_overrides' => [
        'memory_limit'        => '256M',
    ],

];
```

Don't forget to clear config cache

```
php artisan config:clear
```

Comment: Still same issue.